# Send Outlook email with attachment and signature

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to send an Outlook email with attachment and signature.

Below is my VBA code.

I am receiving error "Transport failedtoconnect server". It seems that I am not giving a correct SMTPserver address.

Further I need to write signature with company logo.

```
Sub Outlook()

    Dim Mail_Object As Object
    Dim Config As Object
    Dim SMTP_Config As Variant
    Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Send_To, Email_Cc, Email_Body As      String
    Dim Current_date As Date


    Current_date = DateValue(Now)
    Email_Subject = "Daily Pending IMs Report (" & Current_date & ")"
    Email_Send_From = "report@xxxx.ae"
    Email_Send_To = "yyyyyy@gmail.com"
    'Email_Cc = "vvvvvv@telenor.com.pk"

    Email_Body = "Dear All," & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "Kindly find Daily Pending IMs Report in the attached files."

    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    On Error GoTo debugs
    Set Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Config.Load -1
    Set SMTP_Config = Config.Fields
    With SMTP_Config
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'NTLM method
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 587
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "report@xxxx.ae"
     .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "nnnnnn"
     .Update
    End With

    With Mail_Object
        Set .Configuration = Config
    End With

    'enter code here
    Mail_Object.Subject = Email_Subject
    Mail_Object.From = Email_Send_From
    Mail_Object.To = Email_Send_To
    Mail_Object.TextBody = Email_Body
    Mail_Object.cc = Email_Cc
    'Mail_Object.AddAttachment "C:\Pending IMs\Pending IMs.pdf"


    Mail_Object.Send

debugs:
    If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: This isnt vb.net is it VBscript? Please edit your tag accordingly. Thanks

Comment: edited.................

Comment: Thanks. Some people - like me. Flag tags they don't know much about as ignored. Others only search look at questions with tags they know about. So correct tagging will probably help get you an answer.

Comment: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211195/outlook-email-and-signature-from-excel-vba-body-vs-htmlbody/36211843?noredirect=1#comment60081357_36211843) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using outlook then you don't need **`CDO.Configuration`**

Simply remove all the configurations,

```
'// Code will work on Outlook & Excel 2010
Option Explicit
Sub Outlook()
    Dim olItem As Object ' Outlook MailItem
    Dim App As Object ' Outlook Application
    Dim Email_Subject, Email_To, Email_Cc, Email_Body As String
    Dim Current_date As Date

    Set App = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olItem = App.CreateItem(olMailItem) ' olMailItem

'   // add signature
    With olItem
        .Display
    End With

    Current_date = DateValue(Now)
    Email_Subject = "Daily Pending IMs Report (" & Current_date & ")"
    Email_To = "yyyyyy@gmail.com"

    Email_Body = "Dear All," & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & "See Report in the attached files."

    Set olItem.SendUsingAccount = App.Session.Accounts.Item(2)

    With olItem
        .Subject = Email_Subject
        .To = Email_To
        .HTMLBody = Email_Body & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & .HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add ("C:\Temp\file001.pdf") ' update Attachment Path
       '.Send ' Send directly
        .Display ' Display it
    End With

'    // Clean up
    Set olItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Remember the code will work on Outlook & Excel

***Tested on Outlook 2010***

Comment: This Code is working fine,However This email is generated from my Basic out look account. and not as per my "from Code". As i have configured two outlook accounts and i want to send it my specific account.

Comment: @user2317074 sry add the code wrong place, i have tested now it should work, see update now, should be `Set Mail_Object.SendUsingAccount = App.Session.Accounts.Item(2)` before `With Mail_Object`

Comment: @Om3r...It Works...Thanks a lot for your cooperation