# Outlook Email and Signature from Excel VBA - .Body vs .HTMLbody

Tags: vba, excel, email, outlook, signature

I have a button on my worksheet to send an email (plus more, but not important).  I want my default signature with its HTML formatting but neither option is producing the results I want:

- `.Body` produces the correct body (fonts and carriage returns) but the signature is plain text
- `.HMTLBody` produces the correct signature but the body for some reason, the font goes to Times New Roman instead of the default Calibri, and the carriage returns don't work whether I use `vbNewLine`, `vbCr`, or `vbCrLf`

Am I just S.O.L.?  Do I need to just pick one and deal with it, or is there a way for me to have my cake and eat it too?

**Code:**

```
    .Display         ' need to display email first for signature to work
    .Subject = Title
    .To = ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value ' <-- Put email of the recipient here
    .CC = "" ' <-- Put email of 'copy to' recipient here
    .HTMLBody = "Thank you for the opportunity to bid on " & ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & ". " & _
        " Please read our attached proposal in its entirety to be sure of all inclusions, exclusions, and products proposed.  Give us a call with any questions or concerns." & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Thank you," & _
        .HTMLBody      ' Adds default signature
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile
```

#### Update:

**Final working code thanks to the help of both answers below:**

```
.Display         ' We need to display email first for signature to be added
.Subject = Title
.To = ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value
.CC = ""
.HTMLBody = "<font face=""calibri"" style=""font-size:11pt;"">Thank you for the opportunity to bid on " & ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & ". " & " Please read our attached proposal in its entirety to be sure of all inclusions, exclusions, and products proposed.  Give us a call with any questions or concerns." & _
    "<br><br>" & _
    "Thank you," & _
    .HTMLBody & "</font>"   ' Adds default signature
.Attachments.Add PdfFile
```

Comment: This is a known issue with Outlook - it simply ignores your HTML font selection and falls back to TNR. [This thread on Litmus](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/982-outlook-overrides-font-to-times-new-roman) gives some workarounds.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the HTMLBody property, make sure you merge the existing `HTMLBody` (with the signature) and your new data - you cannot just concatenate two HTML strings and expects a valid HTML.
find the position of the `"<body"` string, find the position of the next ">" (to take care of the body elements with attributes), insert your data after that ">".

Comment: you lost me.  you have 24k rep so I assume you know what you're talking about, but I don't.  I don't actually use `html` code in my signature, only a logo image and some font sizes and colors formatted through Outlook's signature dialog.  That being said, I do know quite a bit about html so please let me know if there a way to alter my VBA code to do what you are suggesting?  Do you need to see all of the code?

Comment: ok, now I see what you mean when I see Dani's answer but I still can't get my signature in there

Comment: Still working on it.  I think I have it solved, but now suddenly, overnight my Excel 2016 got corrupted!  It is crashing everytime I try to save any file!  So I am dealing with that now.

Comment: latest code posted above.  I'm still not 100% sure what you mean by Concatenating  2 HTML strings.  What were the 2 different strings I was trying to concatenate?

Comment: btw - Looks like just that workbook I was working on got corrupted.  very weird.  Started with a new workbook and everything is working again.

Comment: You cannot have something like .HTMLBody = "some HTML" & .HTMLBody & "more HTML".

Comment: Only because Outlook attempts to parse the invalid HTML. Don't blame it if it gets something wrong, such as font or color.

Answer (score 2):

try to insert your data into the properly html tags:

```
.HTMLBody = "<font face=""verdana"" color=""black"">This is some text!</font>"
```

for spaces you must to add this tag `"<br>"`, For example:

```
.HTMLBody = "<font face=""calibri"" color=""black""> hello <br>"
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & " how <br>" & " are <br>" & " you?</font>"
```

result in:

hello

---

how

---

are

---

you?

**Edit2**

In order to insert images (signature as images) you could use the following code:

**1 step.** Copy this code an paste in class module and name that class module like "MailOptions"

```
Private Message As CDO.Message
Private Attachment, Expression, Matches, FilenameMatch, i

Public Sub PrepareMessageWithEmbeddedImages(ByVal FromAddress, ByVal ToAddress, ByVal Subject, ByVal HtmlContent)

    Set Expression = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Expression.Pattern = "\<EMBEDDEDIMAGE\:(.+?)\>"
    Expression.IgnoreCase = True
    Expression.Global = False 'one match at a time

    Set Message = New CDO.Message
    Message.From = FromAddress
    Message.To = ToAddress
    Message.Subject = Subject

    'Find matches in email body, incrementally increasing the auto-assigned attachment identifiers
    i = 1
    While Expression.Test(HtmlContent)
        FilenameMatch = Expression.Execute(HtmlContent).Item(0).SubMatches(0)
        Set Attachment = Message.AddAttachment(FilenameMatch)
        Attachment.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-ID") = "<attachedimage" & i & ">" ' set an ID we can refer to in HTML
        Attachment.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:Content-Disposition") = "inline" ' "hide" the attachment
        Attachment.Fields.Update
        HtmlContent = Expression.Replace(HtmlContent, "cid:attachedimage" & i) ' update the HTML to refer to the actual attachment
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    Message.HTMLBody = HtmlContent
End Sub

Public Sub SendMessageBySMTP(ByVal SmtpServer, ByVal SmtpUsername, ByVal SmtpPassword, ByVal UseSSL)
    Dim Configuration
    Set Configuration = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    Configuration.Load -1 ' CDO Source Defaults
    Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SmtpServer
    'Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = SmtpPort
    Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 30

    If SmtpUsername <> "" Then
        Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = SmtpUsername
        Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = SmtpPassword
    End If
    Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = UseSSL
    Configuration.Fields.Update
    Set Message.Configuration = Configuration
    Message.Send
End Sub
```

**Step 2.** In an standar module you will elaborate your .html content and instantiate a object from the class:

```
public sub send_mail()

Dim signature As String
dim mail_sender as new MailOptions 'here you are instantiating an object from the class module created previously
dim content as string

signature = "C:\Users\your_user\Documents\your_signature.png"

content = "<font face=""verdana"" color=""black"">This is some text!</font>"
content = content & "<img src=""<EMBEDDEDIMAGE:" & signature & " >"" />"

mail_sender.PrepareMessageWithEmbeddedImages _
                    FromAddress:="chrism_mail@blablabla.com", _
                    ToAddress:="addressee_mail@blablabla.com", _
                    Subject:="your_subject", _
                    HtmlContent:=content

'your_Smtp_Server, for example: RelayServer.Contoso.com
correos.SendMessageBySMTP "your_Smtp_Server", "your_network_user_account", "your_network_user_account_password", False

end sub
```

Comment: This does get the font correct, however, the signature is not added at all.

Comment: When I step through the code, the signature is there when the email is first displayed, and it stays there as the email is filled out until the `.HTMLBody` is inserted, then it disappears.

Comment: I think its a matter of where or if to use the `</font>` tag.  when I remove it, I am good to go.

Comment: You cannot concatenate 2 HTML stings - the value returned by HTMLBody is a fully qualified HTML string starting with the html tag - if you add any extra HTML, it will be added outside of the HTML document.

Comment: @DaniAya Thank you for all of that, but an image is only a part of my signature, not the signature itself.  I do have it working now, not sure what was going on with the `</font>` tag but it must have had something to do with the fact that my Workbook got corrupted somehow while I was working on this last night.  Made a new one and its all good now.  I guess I will update my original post to show my working code.  Still contemplating the check mark as you are both somewhat correct.