# How to create a table from my text in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

the below code extracts data from excel file and consolidates all of it by email addresses and sends the data to the corresponding email addresses. It works fine but i'm looking to make the data look better. Is there a way to make a table out of the below information?

I would like the email to have a header like the below:

```
|_____|_____|_____|_____|
|_____|_____|_____|_____|
```

I've seen temp tables for an OFT file, but not directly in excel, using the following code, but i'm unsure how to do the same in this code:

```
tmpTbl = tmpTbl & "<tr><td></td><td></td><td align=""center"">*Company</td></tr></table>"
```

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Consolidate()

    #If Early Then
        Dim emailInformation As New Scripting.Dictionary
    #Else
        Dim emailInformation As Object
        Set emailInformation = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    #End If

    GetEmailInformation emailInformation
    SendInfoEmail emailInformation

End Sub

Sub GetEmailInformation(emailInformation As Object)

    Dim rg As Range
    Dim sngRow As Range
    Dim emailAddress As String
    Dim myAppInfo As AppInfo
    Dim AppInfos As Collection

    Set rg = Range("A1").CurrentRegion           ' Assuming the list starts in A1 and DOES NOT contain empty row
    Set rg = rg.Offset(1).Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1) ' Cut the headings

    For Each sngRow In rg.Rows

        emailAddress = sngRow.Cells(1, 1)

        Set myAppInfo = New AppInfo
        With myAppInfo
            .app = sngRow.Cells(1, 2)            'code
            .version = sngRow.Cells(1, 3)        'Company Name
            .ticker = sngRow.Cells(1, 4)         'Abbreviation
            .group = sngRow.Cells(1, 5)          'group sub group
            .lead = sngRow.Cells(1, 6)           'leader
            .banker = sngRow.Cells(1, 7)         'bank
            .analyst = sngRow.Cells(1, 8)        'analyst
            .otw = sngRow.Cells(1, 9)            'at
            .rating = sngRow.Cells(1, 10)        'rank
            .watchlist = sngRow.Cells(1, 11)     'Comments
            .legal = sngRow.Cells(1, 12)         'notes
            .add = sngRow.Cells(1, 13)           'Date
            .last = sngRow.Cells(1, 14)          'Updated
            .id = sngRow.Cells(1, 15)            'ID
        End With

        If emailInformation.Exists(emailAddress) Then
            emailInformation.item(emailAddress).add myAppInfo
        Else
            Set AppInfos = New Collection
            AppInfos.add myAppInfo
            emailInformation.add emailAddress, AppInfos
        End If

    Next

End Sub

Sub SendInfoEmail(emailInformation As Object)

    Dim sBody As String
    Dim sBodyStart As String
    Dim sBodyInfo As String
    Dim sBodyEnd As String
    Dim emailAdress As Variant
    Dim colLines As Collection
    Dim line As Variant

    sBodyStart = "Hi, please find your info below:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    For Each emailAdress In emailInformation
        Set colLines = emailInformation(emailAdress)
        sBodyInfo = ""
        For Each line In colLines
            sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & _
                        "Code: " & line.app & vbTab & "Company Name:   " & line.app & vbTab & "abbreviation:   " & line.abbreviation & vbTab & "Group Sub Group:   " & line.group & vbTab & "Bank:   " & line.lead & vbTab & "Analyst:   " & line.analyst & vbTab & "at:   " & line.at & vbTab & "Rank:   " & line.rank & vbTab & "Comments:   " & line.comments & vbTab & "Notes:   " & line.notes & vbTab & "Date:   " & line.add & vbTab & "Updated:   " & line.updated & vbTab & "ID:   " & line.id & vbCrLf
        Next
        sBodyEnd = "Best Regards," & vbCrLf & _
                   "Tom"

        sBody = sBodyStart & sBodyInfo & sBodyEnd
        SendEmail emailAdress, "Info", sBody
    Next

End Sub

Sub SendEmail(ByVal sTo As String _
              , ByVal sSubject As String _
               , ByVal sBody As String _
                , Optional ByRef coll As Collection)

    #If Early Then
        Dim ol As Outlook.Application
        Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    #Else
        Dim ol As Object
        Dim outMail As Object
        Set ol = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    #End If

    Set outMail = ol.CreateItem(0)

    With outMail
        .To = sTo
        .Subject = sSubject
        .Body = sBody
        .VotingOptions = "Accept;Reject"
        .Importance = 2

        If Not (coll Is Nothing) Then
            Dim item As Variant
            For Each item In coll
                .Attachments.add item
            Next
        End If

        .Display
        .Send
    End With

    Set outMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: How about copying the data and pasting special as pdf/image?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the plain text `Body` property, construct a valid HTML string with a table and assign it to the `HTMLBody` property.

Comment: Could you give me a little more direction please? this is my first VBA project, so i'm very much a beginner

Comment: Do you know HTML? If not, and you've already admitted you don't know VBA then it's a steep learning curve. Maybe you should begin with learning some basics in VBA, then learning some basics in HTML and then go on from there. There is no "push a button"-solution to this.

Comment: @Omar You look like you've already got the basic HTML for your table, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211843/2344413) looks like it may have some good info for you on creating an HTML email instead of plain text.

Answer (score 1):

I have no obvious means of testing this code so it might contain syntax errors.  I believe I have included enough explanations to allow you to fix the code if necessary.  If not, post the statement with the error it gives and I will diagnose the cause.

I have used the simplest possible Html. If you need more formatting, I can give you some suggestions.

An Html table is: `<table> ... <table>`

An Html row is: `<tr> ... </tr>`

An Html cell is: `<td> ... </td>`

An Html paragraph is: `<p> ... </p>`

Initalise `sBodyStart` and `sBodyEnd`:

```
sBodyStart = "<p>Hi, please find your info below:</p>"
sBodyEnd = "<p>Best Regards,<br>Tom</p>"
```

Add to your declarations:

```
Dim CellValue As Variant
```

Replace `sbodyInfo = ""` to `Next` with:

```
sBodyInfo = "<table>"

sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & "<tr>"
For Each CellValue in Array("Code", "Company Name", "Abbreviation", _
                            "Group Sub Group", "Bank", "Analyst", _
                            "At","Rank","Comments","Notes","Date", _
                            "Updated","ID")
  sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & "<td>" & CellValue & "</td>"
Next
sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & "</tr>"

For Each line In colLines

  sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & "<tr>"
  For Each CellValue in Array(line.app, line.app, line.abbreviation, _
                              line.group, line.lead, line.analyst, _
                              line.at, line.rank, line.comments, _
                              line.notes, line.add, line.updated, line.id)
    sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & "<td>" & CellValue & "</td>"
  Next
  sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & "</tr>"

Next

sBodyInfo = sBodyInfo & "</table>"
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance with this! It's giving me an error with this section:  For Each CellValue in Array(line.app, line.app, line.abbreviation, _
                              line.group, line.lead, line.analyst, _
                              line.at, line.rank, line.comments, _
stating that there is a compile error Expected: list separator or )

it highlighted the "sBodyInfo ="

Comment: Okay, fixed the above error, now it is giving me an error with : "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method" It is highlighting the same section. For Each CellValue In Array(line.app, line.version, line.ticker, _
                              line.groupo, line.lead, line.analyst, _
                              line.otw, line.rating, line.watchlist, _
                              line.legal, line.add, line.Update, line.id)

Comment: This is why I argument for you to learn basic VBA in the first place. Internet is full of information on this. If you feel inclined, try this:
http://www.homeandlearn.org/

Comment: My last comment disappeared,  I hope this one is stays.  I built the two `For Each` statements from your assignment statement which I did not check.  You have the value `line.app` twice.  Above; you have `line.ticker` and not `app.abbreviation`.   You need to check that each of these values is a member of `AppInfo`.

Comment: @peakpeak Based on your pervious comment, I did rent a copy of VBA for dummies to grasp the basic concepts. However, contrary to your recommendation, everyone I have spoken to, with VBA/programming knowledge, has told me it all comes with practice & guidance. I am here seeking guidance.

Comment: @TonyDallimore Thank you, I did go back and review my AppInfo module & correct the errors. the code runs with no errors, but it doesn't send any emails strangely. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you single-step through relevant parts of your code? Set a breakpoint before email-relevant code.

Comment: @Omar  I agree with peakpeak, you will have to step through the code checking that variables are being set to the values you expected. In `Consolidate()`, I would add Debug.Prints after `GetEmailInformation emailInformation` to output the contents of `emailInformation` to confirm it contains what I expected.

Comment: @Omar. I did not use dictionaries, collections or user types in my first VBA project or my second. I do not understand why you need such a complicated solution.  Why copy the contents of the worksheet to a dictionary then run the email generation off the dictionary?  Why not run email generation off the worksheet?

Comment: @Omar I agree that there is no substitute for experience but you need to build up slowly. There are many online tutorials, some of which look very good.  _VBA For Dummies_ would not be right for me. I visited a large library and borrowed several Excel VBA primers.  I tried all at home and selected the one I liked best which I bought as a permanent reference.  In the first error you reported, the last line of a multiline statement was missing.  If you do not know enough to recognise that a statement is not finished, your knowledge of the basics is not ready for something so complicated.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I am very aware of my need for a solid foundation, but thought I'd take a chance on this. I am still very young and by no means have a background in tech. I'll keep these pointers in mind if I have build up the courage again to try another project.

Comment: @Omar Don't give up; set your sights lower for a while.  (1) Try to send simple emails from Excel to yourself and a few friends.  (2) I am unclear why you want to use a dictionary and I am not sure what you are trying will work.  Experiment and see what you can load to a dictionary and or a collection. No you know how to get data out of a collection within a dictionary?  (3) Try creating some HTML files.  Do they look the way you want? Try some CSS.  I find https://www.w3schools.com very helpful.  (4) Try putting all this separate experience together.  Learn to walk before trying to run.